# Sending variable to search page

Tags: wordpress

I`ve made this action:

```
add_action( 'init', 'advanced_search_query' );
function advanced_search_query( $query ) {  
    if ( isset($_GET['make']) && isset($_GET['model']) && isset($_GET['fuel']) ) {

        $all_products = [];

        $inner_cats = get_terms(['taxonomy' => 'product_cat','hide_empty' => false, 'parent' => $_GET['model']]);

        foreach ($inner_cats as $cat) {

            if ($_GET['fuel'] == 0)
                $fuel_cat = get_terms(['taxonomy' => 'product_cat','hide_empty' => false, 'parent' => $cat->term_id, 'name' => 'Diesel']);  
            elseif ($_GET['fuel'] == 1)
                $fuel_cat = get_terms(['taxonomy' => 'product_cat','hide_empty' => false, 'parent' => $cat->term_id, 'name' => 'Benzin']);  

            $args = array( 
                'post_type' => 'product',
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                        'terms' => $fuel_cat[0]->term_id,
                        'operator' => 'IN',
                    )
                )
             );

            $products = get_posts( $args );     

            if ($products) {
                foreach ($products as $prd) {
                    $all_products[] = $prd;
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Now what I am strugling with is sending the `$all_products` to my search page and loop them. Tried to redirect to the search page like `wp_safe_recirect('domain.com?s=""')` with empty `s` parameter and use the `all_results` there. Also tried to set the variable as global but again couldnt reach it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the following?

```
if ($products) {
foreach ($products as $prd) {
    $all_products[] = $prd;
    ?>
    <script>window.location.href="domain.com?s=''"</script>
    <?php
 }
}
```